# KafkaTemplate adds a newline character when testing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, junit, spring-kafka

The function I'm testing is this, the result and the all expected status works fine.

```java
private InstanceGetDTO updateInstance(...) {
        ...

        ConferenceInstanceDTO conferenceInstanceDTO = ConferenceInstanceDTO.builder().instance(instanceMapper.mapInstanceToInstanceGetDTO(instance)).conferenceGetDTO(conferenceGetDTO).build();
        String topic = conference.getProvider() + "-update-instance";
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, conferenceInstanceDTO);

        return instanceMapper.mapInstanceToInstanceGetDTO(instance);
    }
```

However, I wanted to test the kafka topic and the body is correct also.

```java
verify(kafkaTemplate).send(eq(provider + "-update-instance"), eq(conferenceInstanceDTO));
```

I wrote this, which I'm not 100% sure that's the correct way to do this. I got an error about they're not matching.

**Expected:**

```java
kafkaTemplate.send(
    "zoom-update-instance",
    ConferenceInstanceDTO(...);
);
```

**Actual:**

```java
kafkaTemplate.send(
    "zoom-update-instance",
    ConferenceInstanceDTO(...); <-- (The DTO is matching)
);
       <-- Newline
```

As you can see, it's adding a newline character outside the function call. How can I test this without that newline. Or, how can I prevent that adding new-line.

**Updated**

**ConferenceInstanceDTO**

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@Setter
@ToString
public class ConferenceInstanceDTO {
    private InstanceGetDTO instance;
    private ConferenceGetDTO conferenceGetDTO;
}
```

InstanceGetDTO and ConferenceGetDTO has same annotations with different fields.

Comment: Unclear where you see a new line. Also, looks like you're testing a mock/spy?

Comment: Yes I'm testing a mock, which does nothing when send method runs but I wanted to test if the created DTO and the topic are correct.

Comment: Kafka itself stores/sends bytes. Not strings, and does not insert newlines on its own... So, what is your value serializer setting? Does your serializer call `toString()` and add any newlines? For example, `ConferenceInstanceDTO` uses Lombok? Can you show that class?

Comment: Yes, ```ConferenceInstanceDTO``` uses Lombok, uses its ```toString()```. Kafka uses ```StringSerializer.class``` as Key Serizalizer, and ```JsonSerializer.class``` as Value Serializer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Kafka problem. Can you construct a `new ConferenceInstanceDTO()` and just print it? Is there a new-line in any of the fields of the nested DTO classes? Also, tests don't care about the indentation/spacing of your source code, so I don't quite understand what you mean by "Actual" and "<-- Newline"